# Перезаписать атрибут в сообщении struct nl_msg (netlink, libnl)

Tags: linux, ipc

Для формирования netlink сообщения библиотека `libnl` предоставляет функции типа `nla_put_...`. Можно ли каким-либо образом перезаписать значение атрибута, добавленное одной из таких функций, без удаления всего сообщения и составления его заново?

Comment: Непонятно, в чём ваш вопрос. Есть функция `npa_put`, которая умеет писать любой атрибут прямо в сообщение. Чем она вас не устраивает? Что вы хотите получить?

Comment: @PakUula , меня волнует, какое поведение будет, если я уже записал определенный атрибут, а потом опять поверх еще раз записал его же (да, это все будет с помощью `nla_put`). Что с памятью, безопасно ли это, правильно ли и т.д.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я понял в чём ваш вопрос. Нет, нельзя.

Атрибуты представлены в памяти последовательно, один за другим. Память каждого атрибута устроена так: `{ тип_атрибута, длина_атрибута, значение_атрибута }`

`nla_put` всегда добавляет атрибут в хвост сообщения. Записав атрибут `nla_put` передвигает указатель конца сообщения на байт, следующий за добавленным атрибутом. Если атрибут не может уместиться в остаток памяти, аллоцированной для сообщения, то `nla_put` возвращает отрицательный код ошибки.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ. Дополню своими соображениями. Я почитал мануал более внимательно и посмотрел исходники. Обнаружил, что в nla_put сначала вызывается nla_reserve (выделение памяти), а потом обычный memcpy с адресом назначения, полученным с помощью функции nla_data от только что выделенного и заполненного атрибута (это структура nlattr, туда заполняется его тип и длина). Также существует функция nla_find, которая позволяет по типу атрибута получить указатель на эту структуру. Таким образом, можно, зная тип атрибута, получить указатель на него, вызвать nla_data и записать новое значение

Comment: @Аркадий да, если тип остаётся тем же самым, то можно. Ещё есть `nla_next` для итерации по атрибутам. Но я бы не стал )

Comment: Да, принимаю, что тип тот же самый. А почему не стали бы? (Чисто из интереса :) )

Comment: @Аркадий я предпочитаю хранить свои данные в своих форматах, а чужие использовать только для вызовов API или отправки сообщений. Упаковал в пакет и отправил, никаких переделок в последний момент.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо еще раз